# match postgres datestyle in heroku and development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date, heroku

I'm using rails 4.1 with heroku.
I have a problem with the date style of postgres.
When I run the app on my local machine everything works well, but after pushing to heroku it fails.

From heroku logs:

```
(PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "30/11/2014", Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.`
```

I executed

```
heroku config:add TZ="Asia/Jerusalem"
```

and

```
heroku pg:psql SET datestyle = "SQL, DMY";
```

but there's still the same error message.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at the parser.

Solved by not using:

`Date.new(date[0][6..9].to_i, date[0][3..4].to_i,date[0][0..1].to_i)`

But using:

`"#{date[0][6..9].to_i}-#{date[0][3..4].to_i}-#{date[0][0..1].to_i}"`

One more thing is to use `-` instead of `\` for separators, and use date as `year-month-day` and not the opposite - that way it can't be understood differently in different environments.

Answer (score 0):

that is a problem when you try to query a data column with an inappropriate string.

```
Participant.where(updated_at: "30/11/2014")
PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "30/11/2014"
LINE 1: ...articipants"  WHERE "participants"."updated_at" = '30/11/201...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

parse the string on the ruby side or provide a properly formatted string

Comment: I changed the parsing and now it works on heroku but not on local machine.  I get the same error message that heroku logged, now on my local machine.

Comment: that does not make any sense